# Scroll down in Safari on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari

When using Safari from iPhone/iPad I can scroll back to the top of the page in one touch by touching the upper bar of the device. Is there any similar trick for scrolling to the bottom of the page? Is there **any** way of scrolling down fast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no keypress or gesture to do this unfortunately.

But here is a quick way to achieve a similar thing.

1. Create a new bookmark in safari (of any web page)
2. Edit this bookmark (press edit in bookmark screen)
3. Rename the bookmark to End
4. In the address field cut and paste this text

   ```
   javascript:scroll(0,document.getElementsByTagName( 'body')%5B0%5D.scrollHeight);
   ```

Once you save this bookmark, you will be able to hit the bookmark button, select End and it will take you to the bottom of the web page.  I know it's not as simple as the current scroll to top feature (this solution requires two taps), but its really the only option at the moment.

Comment: There is a bookmarks bar like on the Mac in newer versions of iOS for iPad, so that would be one tap.

Comment: @waiwai933 good point :)

Comment: Why or why is there no way to "quick-scroll" ?

Comment: Some more context that I needed: Add a bookmark, edit it, change the URL to that JS code, store it in the «Bookmarks» folder (root), and edit that to move it to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by [@RobZolkos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12550/166704), this more readable script will work in newer versions of iOS. In Rob's Step 4, you can substitute the text:

```
javascript:scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

The [source](http://anetteiren.com/scroll-bottom-page-down-safari-iphone-ipad/) claims this works in iOS 8 and newer. It worked for me under iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to jailbreak, the application Action Menu has a Scroll feature which can scroll both to the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an external keyboard, <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> will scroll to the bottom of the page, and <kbd>⌥ opt</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> will scroll one page down.